# Can't resolve the implicit for a constrained class type parameter

Tags: scala, implicit, type-parameter

```scala
package ir.ashkan.shahnameh

object Implicit {
  sealed trait A
  class B extends A
  class C extends A

  def listOf[T <: A](implicit ts: List[T]): List[T] = ts

  class Module[T <: A] {
    implicit val bList: List[B] = ???
    implicit val cList: List[C] = ???

    listOf[T].toSet // HERE
  }
}
```

Compilation fails:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter ts: List[T] (No implicit view available from Int => T.)
[error]     listOf[T].toSet
[error]           ^
```

Comment: `T` may be `Nothing` may be `B with C` may be `C with A` may be another subtype of `B` or `C` - As such, there is no guarantee there will be an implicit `List[T]` in scope. The best you can do would be `class Module[T <: A](implicit ev: List[T])` and move those two implicit vals to the companion objec of `Module` I believe they should be in the implicit scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Module` requires implicit `List[T]`. You can define imlicit constructor argument for it:

```scala
object Implicit {
  sealed trait A
  class B extends A
  class C extends A

  def listOf[T <: A](implicit ts: List[T]): List[T] = ts
  
  implicit val aList: List[A] = List.empty[A]
  implicit val bList: List[B] = List.empty[B]

  class Module[T <: A](implicit ts: List[T]) {    
    listOf[T].toSet
  }
}

val x = new Implicit.Module[Implicit.B]
```